# Estimate needed disk space for extracting payload and packages using Wix and bundle

Tags: wix, bundle

Is there a possibility to estimate the needed disk space when starting a bundle-exe using wix and the bootstrapper?

As far I see the bootstrapper initially starts to extract it's files to the temp folder. When there's is not enough disk space (which shouln'd take place nowadaways ;-)) it logs some messages and remains in unfriendly state for the end-customer. I'm looking for a method to get to know (maybe just as a guess) if the contained packages are able to be extracted and quit the setup procedure.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @donttellya: Unfortunately no. We put it into the release note and delegated such issues to the hotline